# Create POSIX thread with a void function?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

I tried to create POSIX thread with a void function like this:

```
void thread_func(void* p_Arg)
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, (void*)thread_func, (void*)NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine! But is it safe to cast thread_func to void* in this case?

Comment: why would you do this? where is the problem in declaring the function return `void*` and adding `return 0` at the end? What is the gain? Put your efforts in designing your program, at not into hacking a system for no gain.

Comment: @Jens: I saw a real project in US in which POSIX threads are created like this! I'm not sure why they do that

Comment: It seems that the threads are detached (using pthread_detach) after their creation and run forever! (i.e an infinite loop)

Comment: If they do so, that's their problem. But that they cast a function pointer to `void*` is really bogus. Why not at least cast it to the expected type with `((void*)(*)(void*))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Your code [will crash on IA64](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/19/60162.aspx).  A function pointer cast is [a bug waiting to happen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx).  Just use the correct signature and return a dummy value like 0.

Also note that casting a function pointer (like `void (*)(void*)`) to an object pointer (like `void*`) is also a potentially unsafe operation, since the C standard does not guarantee that object pointers and function pointers have the same representation.  I don't know of any architectures off-hand that use different representations, but it's certainly possible for a function pointer to contain extra context bits not normally present in object pointers.

So you should never cast a function pointer to an object pointer unless you're using an implementation the expressly allows it -- for example, [POSIX systems require](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_12_03) this, so the return value from [`dlsym(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html) can be safely cast from an object pointer to a function pointer.

Comment: `dlsym` is not XSI, it's part of POSIX base (as of 2008). And POSIX requires all pointer types to have the same size and representation. However, this does not mean it's valid to call a function with the wrong function pointer type; that still invokes UB.

Comment: @R..: I based that statement off the Rationale section of the POSIX documentation I linked to: "Implementations supporting the XSI extension, however, do require that an object of type void * can hold a pointer to a function. The result of converting a pointer to a function into a pointer to another data type (except void *) is still undefined".  Do you have a citation that POSIX requires all pointer types to have the same size and representation?

Comment: You're linking to an outdated version. Anyway I over-stated the requirements slightly. See XSH 2.12.3 http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_12_03 for the correct statement: *All function pointer types shall have the same representation as the type pointer to void. Conversion of a function pointer to void * shall not alter the representation. A void * value resulting from such a conversion can be converted back to the original function pointer type, using an explicit cast, without loss of information.*

Comment: Thanks, I missed the fact that I linked to the 2004 spec instead of the 2008 spec.

Answer (score 2):

> is it safe to cast thread_func to void* in this case

This will probably work on many platforms but you should know:

- A `void *` is only guaranteed to be able to store object pointers not function pointers
- Your thread function should return `void *` and there's no completely legal way around that. For example I wonder what will happen when you `pthread_join` with a non-NULL result

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer **to any
>   object type**. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a
>   pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the
>   original pointer.

And of course:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
>   equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call
>   a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the
>   behavior is undeﬁned.

Answer (score 0):

While C compilers are traditionally more permissive (than C++ compilers) when it comes to performing dangerous pointer conversions implicitly, I find it hard to believe that any C compiler would allow you to supply a `void *` argument for a function pointer parameter without generating a boatload of diagnostic messages. Didn't you by any chance forget to include `pthread.h`, thus forcing a pre-C99 compiler to deduce the argument types instead of relying on function prototype for `pthread_create`?

In any case, if you really want to rely on this hack, at least cast the pointer to proper target type, i.e. to `void *(*)(void*)`, not to `void *`

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, (void *(*)(void*)) thread_func, NULL);
```

However, it is in no way safe from the point of view of C language. POSIX can offer you additional guarantees that can make it "safer", but I woudn't do it anyway.

Declare your thread function properly, with `void *` return type, and get rid of this useless hack.

Comment: I included pthread.h to the source file and the code is compiled successfully without warning messages.

Comment: @user1603936: That would simply mean that the compiler you are using far oversteps the limits of what's reasonable when it comes to implicit pointer conversions. Are you using GCC by any chance? In order to make GCC at least remotely practically usable you need to run it with `-ansi -pedantic-errors` command line switches. Without those switches the compiler has only superficial relation to real C language.

Comment: The only dangerous conversion that a decent C compiler would do implicitly without yelling would be other object pointers from and to `void*`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ AndreyT: Yes, I used gcc to compile the code. Tried with your switches and I got compilation errors. Thanks Andrey! :)

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: Yes, that's the only conversions (from the "dangerous" group) allowed by the language to be done implicitly.

Comment: @AndreyT: `-std=c99`, not `-ansi`. The `-ansi` option is an alias for `-std=c89` which is probably not what anybody wants. (POSIX for example extends C99, not C89, so it's not possible to be writing a modern POSIX program on C89.)